An akward integral representation of Bessel function of zero order in Morse-Feshbach
In the popular textbook "Methods of Theoretical Physics" by Morse - Feshbach to evaluate Green function of 1+1D Klein Gordon equation, they have reached to an integral (p. 855, equ. 7.3.37)

\begin{equation}
    h(R,\tau)=\frac{1}{2\pi c} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{i\left(\sqrt{(\frac{\omega}{c})^2-k^2}R-\omega\tau\right)}}{\sqrt{(\frac{\omega}{c})^2-k^2}} d\omega
\end{equation}

This is alright.
For $R>c\tau$, $h(R,\tau)=0$, this is also alright due to causility condition and they selected contour of integration as

Q.1. Why this type of contour ?
For $R<c\tau$, they introduce a new variable $v$, such that $\tau=\left|\sqrt{\tau^2-(\frac{R}{c})^2}\right|\cosh v $ and takes $\omega=ck \cosh x$, and got

\begin{equation}
    h(R,\tau)=\frac{c}{2\pi i} \int_{\infty+\frac{3}{2}\pi i}^{\infty-\frac{1}{2}\pi i} \exp{\left[-i kc \left|\tau^2-\left(\frac{R}{c}\right)^2\right|\cosh (x-v)\right]}dx
\end{equation}

Q.2. This is how ?
And then they substitute $(x-v)=i\xi$ and reached
\begin{equation}
    h(R,\tau)=\frac{c}{2\pi} \int_{-i\infty+\frac{3}{2}\pi i}^{-i\infty-\frac{1}{2}\pi i} \exp{\left[-i kc \left|\tau^2-\left(\frac{R}{c}\right)^2\right|\cosh\xi\right]}d\xi
\end{equation}
This is alright and at last they claimed that this is an integral representation of Bessel function of zero order and got the final result,

\begin{equation}
    h(R,\tau)=-c J_0\left[kc \sqrt{\tau^2-\left(\frac{R}{c}\right)^2}\right]
\end{equation}

But the problem is how this is an integral representation of $J_0$, I have tried to get it from another well known integral representations, are given by the popular textbook on Bessel function by G.N. Watson and can't get.
Q.3. How this integral representation becomes and what is corresponding logic behind taking the contour is given above ?

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/823453/2451
